# Add/Remove nodes in a line graph in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes, jqplot

Is it possible to start with a plot (in jqPlot), either as a function or a list of points, and make it possible for the user to add or remove nodes on the graph? Ideally, it would keep the line/curve the same and just add another node, though with some curves that obviously won't be possible. It isn't crucial that the existing nodes stay in the same place; in fact, it is crucial that the nodes remain equidistant along the x-axis. I'm using Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I do not understand what you are after.  You have a line graph defined by a series of points, you want to add points on user click (for example), but then not adjust the curve to fit with that new point?

Comment: The curve should fit all the points of course, but if I make a new point between two existing ones, the points should all move so that they stay equally spaced, as opposed to having those three points be closer together than all the others.